# n98-magerun extension:list

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1

I am new to working on the command line and have tried to venture in to using n98-magerun.

So far I have

- downloaded it
- placed it in the folder that holds all my sites
- sym-linked it to the folder i am working in
- aliased it with mag
- followed the first half of tutorial 1 in the [alan storms "quickies"](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/47974204176/introduction-to-n98-magerun) blog

But I am now at a sticking point, which is the command

`mag extension:list`

when I input this the cursor moves to the following blank line and after about a minuet of seemingly doing nothing the cursor moves to another new line (resetting itself) and returns nothing.

I have tried other command such as

`mag --help` and `mag dev:module:rewrite:list`

These work as expected, so why won't `mag extension:list` return anything? (I was expecting to get a full list of all the modules in my Magento install)

Comment: Have you tried copying the phar into your project and running it?

Comment: No, it is my understanding that linking a file to a folder is excatly the same as having the file in that folder, just without the extra space being used up or have I being misguided?

Comment: The extension:list command is only a lightweight wrapper for the mage connect client. If you need a list of all installed models you should use the command "dev:module:list".

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the command with real path to the script

```
php /path/to/n98-magerun.phar extension:list
```

from your magento directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that has produce the same result. Everything else i've tried works when I use the alias.